# Having combination of Suggest and Search in Azure Search

Tags: azure-search-.net-sdk

I am using Azure Search SDK for our Search Scenario. I have the textbox in the UI to display the results in the UX. Our experience is: As the user types in, the type-ahead result should display the result.
So, we are using the suggest "SuggestAsync" method to yield the results. 
So, lets say I am searching for "Azure Infra" (and I have "Azure Infrastructure" within the search index document), it gives Azure Infrastructure. However, if I reverse the sequence like "Infrastructure Azure", it won't give any results.
Doing some POC, it came that the "SearchAsync" enables the search of this type. However, if I type in "Infrastructure Az", this won't suggest the "Azure Infrastructure".

What we want is the ability to enable a combination of Suggest and Search in the experience i.e. "Azure Infra" and "Infrastructure azure" both should yield "Azure Infrastructure" as one of the main results.

Any pointers of help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-lucene-examples) that goes over the Lucene query syntax with [fuzzy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-lucene-examples#example-3-fuzzy-search) search. You can set `UseFuzzyMatching` property of the `SuggestParameters` class to true for use in your [auto-complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-autocomplete-tutorial#suggest-function) search.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I'll check this out. One thing I did try was, changing the API Method to SearchAsyn with QueryType as Lucene also helped in achieving this.However, not sure if that was the right way to do it.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. Let me try something else.